# How to get file "Path" stored in this json file using Python?

Tags: python, json

## json file

```
[{"Attachment": [
{
    "Page:": [
    {
        "Path": "a\\b\\c.pdf",  #field to be extracted
        "PageID": 1
    }
    ]
}
],
"ID": 13221}]
```

I tried the following but getting the TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

```
with open(file) as f:
    d = json.load(f)
print(d[0]['Attachment']['Page']['Path'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d[0]['Attachment']` is a list, so is `d[0]['Attachment'][0]['Page:']`.

```
with open(file) as f:
    d = json.load(f)
print(d[0]['Attachment'][0]['Page:'][0]['Path'])
```

will do the job.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the ':' after 'Page', see edited answer.